# most efficient lookup for url caching system for REST API

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

What's the best way to store, index, and lookup text strings (URLs in this case)?

I'm creating a caching system for one of my sites.  It's actually a bit more complex than that, thus the reason I'm rolling my own.  I'm looking for the quickest, most-efficient way to resolve lookups on URLs, which obviously are text strings.

I'm currently using MySQL for a lot of my backend, and obviously I could just throw this in a table as a text field for the URL and its contents and turn on full text indexing, but that just feels slow and fundamentally wrong.  Is there something else I should be looking at, whether it's MySQL or some other tool?  Should I MD5 the URL, does that give me anything?

I've heard interesting things about mongodb too, but not sure if that buys me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached - easy, quick, found everywhere. I use it a lot.

Comment: Went ahead and gave you the correct answer, as I looked into memcached, but I decided to go with redis.  My app is written in Django, and redis appears to be persistent in that it allows me to dump the cache to disk and not just keep resident in memory.

This seems to be a great solution for caching API calls, I really like the simplicity of redis.

Comment: Thank you. Good luck with redis.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a database, not a caching system. The speed difference between it and MySQL is not likely to be huge.

As D Mac mention memcached is an excellent choice for this. You do need to be aware that memcached is a true caching system and can throw your data away at any moment. You must be able to handle that.

A good compromise is redis, which is an in-memory database so it won't throw your data away like memcached will but also it will be an order of magnitude quicker than MySQL or MongoDB. The only downside to redis is that your whole dataset must fit into memory.

Your question contains lots of subquestions but not a lot of detail on what you're actually doing so it's hard to give a good answer.